# How parse and make a table based on a log footprint?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my friends, I want to parse my log file but I don't know how I try to write a good regex but I can't find perfect way to separate my log file feature??? I there any way to this??? size of log file is something around 230 MB should I use Hadoop or spark??

Sample of line in my file :

```
207.213.193.143 [2021-5-12T5:6:0.0+0430] [Get /cdn/profiles/1026106239] 304 0 [[Googlebot-Image/1.0]] 32
207.213.193.143 [2021-5-12T5:6:0.0+0430] [Get images/badge.png] 304 0 [[Googlebot-Image/1.0]] 4
35.110.222.153 [2021-5-12T5:6:0.0+0430] [Get /pages/630180847] 200 52567 [[Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SAMSUNG SM-J710GN Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.133 Mobile Safari/537.36]] 32
35.108.208.99 [2021-5-12T5:6:0.0+0430] [Get images/fav_icon2.ico] 200 23531 [[Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; CAM-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.88 Mobile Safari/537.36]] 20
141.5.121.152 [2021-5-12T6:1:39.0+0430] [Get /pages/1939237153] 200 49742 [[Mozilla/5.0 (Symbian/3; Series60/5.5 Nokia603/113.010.1506; Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1 ) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) NokiaBrowser/8.3.2.21 Mobile Safari/535.1 3gpp-gba]] 28
```

Here's my feature (That may I choose wrong?? correct me if it's):

```
features=['ip', 'timestamp', 'request', 'status', 'size', 'user_agent', 'duration']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to parse my log file but I don't know how I try to write a good
> regex but I can't find perfect **way to separate my log file feature**?

You can try with [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

```
df = (pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep=r"(?<=\]|\d)\s(?=\[|\d)", header=None,
         engine="python", names=features).replace(r"\[?\[(.*?)\]\]?", r"\1", regex=True)
     )
```

Or with [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :

```
pat = r"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\s*)\[(.*)\]\s*\[(.*)\]\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)\s*\[\[(.*)\]\]\s*(\d+)"

df = (pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep="|", header=None)
          .squeeze().str.extract(pat).set_axis(features, axis=1)
     )
```

Output :

```
print(df)
​
                ip               timestamp                       request  status   size                                                                                                                                                              user_agent  duration
0  207.213.193.143  2021-5-12T5:6:0.0+0430  Get /cdn/profiles/1026106239     304      0                                                                                                                                                     Googlebot-Image/1.0        32
1  207.213.193.143  2021-5-12T5:6:0.0+0430          Get images/badge.png     304      0                                                                                                                                                     Googlebot-Image/1.0         4
2   35.110.222.153  2021-5-12T5:6:0.0+0430          Get /pages/630180847     200  52567  Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SAMSUNG SM-J710GN Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/4.0 Chrome/44.0.2403.133 Mobile Safari/537.36        32
3    35.108.208.99  2021-5-12T5:6:0.0+0430      Get images/fav_icon2.ico     200  23531                                               Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; CAM-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.88 Mobile Safari/537.36        20
```

Comment: **NB:** .The python engine tends to be slower than the C engine on most workloads ([*source*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#specifying-the-parser-engine)).

Comment: Can you please seprate request to "http_method" and "url_endpoint"???

Comment: Add this *line/statement* : `df[["http_method", "url_endpoint"]] = df["request"].str.split(expand=True)`

Comment: I get this error : Expected 7 fields in line 73065, saw 8. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: Can you add the line 73065 of your logfile to the example in your question ?

Comment: Added to the last line of example

Comment: I added a second approach with `extract`, can you test it ?